# Как отсортировать v-for объекты по ключу внутри объекта-родителя в шаблоне vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть объект вида:

```
peoples = {
  {sort: 2, name: John},
  {sort: 1, name: Jack}
}
```

Шаблон:

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="(people, index) in peoples">{{people.name}}</li> 
</ul>
```

Вопрос: как отсортировать записи по полю sort?

Comment: А вот этот `peoples` может быть нормальным массивом?

Comment: Нет, массивом быть не может. Так исторически сложилось.

Comment: тогда я вижу только такой вариант. Берём этот пиплз, проходим по нему, складывая каждое значение в массив, сортируем массив и обратно в этот же объект (или новый, не важно) кладём по очереди каждый айтем этого массива. И уже таким пользуемся. Хз. Геморойный немного вариант, но должен сработать.

Answer (score 1):

Объект - несортируемый формат хранения данных в js.
Вы можете отсортировать данные сторонней функцией, сложить в объект, но они лягут туда так, как лежали изначально или как сойдутся звезды =)

Если нельзя перейти к сортируемому хранению (массив), то реализуйте функцию сортировки и обращайтесь к объекту через нее, чтобы вы уже на выходе получали сортированные данные.

Для вывода данных через vue можно уже после рендеринга произвести сортировку на странице через js или jquery, но это некоторый костыль.

Оптимально - переложить в массив